# php imgcopyresampled - alter width of thumbnail

Tags: php

I'm using a thumbnailing script, and I could only find imagecopyresampled to copy a portion of my image and make a square thumbnail out of it.

For once particular thumbnail, I'd like the width to be greater than the height because I want to go for this new layout:

[image]

Here's what I have now, which is too small width-wise for the Latest Artwork section:

[image]

I thought I could accomplish this by adding to the width, `imagecopyresampled($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width+100, $new_height, $width, $height);`... Which only stretched the image, but maintained the thumbnail frame:

[image]

**Here's what I'm going for...** the frame is larger width-wise so I fit more of the image in it.

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to PHP documentation for imagecopyresampled:

`bool imagecopyresampled ( resource $dst_image , resource $src_image , int $dst_x , int $dst_y , int $src_x , int $src_y , int $dst_w , int $dst_h , int $src_w , int $src_h )`

When going from 1 aspect ratio to another without cropping or smart placement you will always stretch an image, it is unavoidable.  If you don't care too much about stretching (or if you aren't changing aspect ratios after-all, your question is unclear on that), then here is similar to how I do that.

```
function resize($width,$height,$data) {
       $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
       imagecopyresampled($new_image, $data, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height,      imagesx($data), imagesy($data));
       $data = $new_image;
    }
```